# Añadir input a checkout Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Pregunto esto porque ya me está volviendo un poco loco...
Sé como a través de mi fichero functions añadir un campo (tipo nif/cif) de la siguiente forma:

```
 function woo_custom_field_checkout($checkout) {
  echo '<div>';
  woocommerce_form_field( 'nif', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class'),
    'required'      => false,       
    'label'       => __('NIF / CIF'),   
    'placeholder'   => __('Ej: 12345678-X'),
    'priority'    => 25
  ), $checkout->get_value( 'nif' ));    // Identificador del campo 
  echo '</div>'; 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', 'woo_custom_field_checkout' );
```

Ahora bien ¿cómo puedo añadir dicho campo **debajo del input nombre empresa** ?
No sé cómo hacer que se mueva ese campo hacia abajo  y lo que encuentro es con un hook que ya no funciona.

Así es como se visualiza por ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]